# Determine the tmux session a shell session belongs to?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, tmux

tmux provides a number of commands in the shell such as `rename-session` which operate on the session that the invoking shell belongs to.

It also provides commands like `list-clients` which list out the different tmux sessions that are currently running.

I am looking for a command along the lines of `tmux pwd` which will echo out the name of the tmux session to which my active shell session belongs.

e.g. Inside tmux session `foo`:

```
$ tmux pwd
foo
```

Is there a command for this, or a roundabout way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing this inside your `tmux` session:

`tmux display-message -p '#S'`